# Issues with RemoteWebdriver XPath

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When running my test not using `RemoteWebDriver`, just using `IWebdriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();`

I can run my tests fine, finding elements, using XPath expressions works fine, but when I switch my settings to using RemoteWebDriver, I get an error for a certain part during my test.

I recieve the following error message:

```
Attempting to find outbound radio input to click
2012-01-18 15:50:11,522 [Simple Test Driver] INFO  SeleniumGridExample.Utils.EventLogger -     The driver is a SeleniumGridExample.Utils.ScreenshotRemoteWebDriver
2012-01-18 15:50:11,522 [Simple Test Driver] INFO  SeleniumGridExample.Utils.EventLogger - Screenshot saved with exception: Session [1326893314795] not available - []
2012-01-18 15:50:11,522 [Simple Test Driver] INFO  SeleniumGridExample.Utils.EventLogger - The driver is a SeleniumGridExample.Utils.ScreenshotRemoteWebDriver
2012-01-18 15:50:11,522 [Simple Test Driver] ERROR SeleniumGridExample.Utils.EventLogger - Screenshot could not be saved: Unexpected error.

<html>
<head>
    <title>Error 501 Method {"USING":"XPATH","VALUE":"//INPUT[CONTAINS(@ID, is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR: 501</h2><pre>Method {"USING":"XPATH","VALUE":"//INPUT[CONTAINS(@ID, is  not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API </pre>
    <p>RequestURI='0_lsDirection_ctrl0_lsLegs_ctrl0_inpSelect')]"}GET /wd/hub/session/1326893314795/screenshot</p>
    <p>
      <i><small>
         <a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org">Powered by Jetty://</a>
         </small>
      </i>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone here know why I get this issue using RemoteWebDriver but not when using the normal `IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using //INPUT[@id='']  . This must work. But better try to use css selectors. Selenium takes some time using expath selectors on IE browsers.